# Sybase - row count

Tags: sybase

Could these counts be different, ever? (in Sybase 15)

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM MY_TABLE
```

and

```
select st.rowcnt 
from sysobjects ob, systabstats st 
where ob.name = "MY_TABLE"
and st.id=ob.id
```

Comment: Why dont you try it?

Comment: I tried. They are same always. But I am thinking there might be an impact of running stats. I am talking about a Sybase database that has around 13 TB of data and I am not a DBA - so new to this world.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, they can be different, for example when there is insert/delete activity going on for the table. That may be tricky to reproduce however.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, both may be different. For example when there is change in the table like `insert`  or `delete` the row. It takes some time to update `rowcnt` in the `systabstats`.

But when you use `count(1)` then it always returns exact count.

Answer (score 0):

This could be different , as data in stats table is not always/exact realtime

Answer (score 0):

yes, possible different due to concurrent DML on the table.